# MongoDB Object key with ES6 template string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to update an array in my collection with this:

```
 var str = "list.0.arr";
    db.collection('connect').update({_id: id}, {$push:  { `${str}`: item}});
```

This exact string works just fine if I do it like this:

```
db.collection('connect').update({_id: id}, {$push:  { "list.0.arr": item}});
```

This is to show that it works, but It's throwing an error `Unexpected token` when I use the first solution.

My question is, how can I get the top solution to work as the Object key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template literals cannot be used as key in an object literal. Use a computed property instead:

```
db.collection('connect').update({_id: id}, {$push: {[str]: item}}); 
//                                                  ^^^^^
```

See also [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242/218196)

Comment: This does not work.  It gives: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`.  I suspect mongo doesn't support this syntax. (Using version 2.6.11)

Comment: @hackel: That has nothing to do with MongoDB, rather with the Node version you are using. See http://node.green for which features are supported in each version.

Answer (score 2):

Create the update document with the string as key prior to using it in the update:

```
var str = "list.0.arr",
    query = { "_id": id },
    update = { "$push": {} };
update["$push"][str] = item;
db.collection('connect').update(query, update);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me after I was almost gave up , var Now = new Date();
    var currMonth = Now.getMonth();
    var currYear = Now.getFullYear();
    console.log(currYear, currMonth);
    var query = {shareId: share},
     inc = { "$inc": {} };
     inc["$inc"][`interactions.views.${currYear}.${currMonth}`] = 1 ;
    ShareStat.findOneAndUpdate(query, inc);