# MongoDB update array element of a document by index in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, meteor

How can I increment the value of an specific element of an array of a MongoDB document in Meteor or nodeJS?

Say, I've following document:

```
{
    "_id" : "4tP6ewe4Z5kwYA3Je",
    "name" : "chutia",
    "address" : "shonir akhra",
    "itemCount" : "4",
    "items" : [ 
        "3", 
        "4",
        "13", 
        "24"
    ]
}
```

I need to increment the `n`'th element of `items` array.  Where `n` is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is:

```
{$inc: {[`items.${idx}`]: 1}}
```

Where `idx` is the array index. Courtesy [MasterAM's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223352/mongodb-update-array-element-of-a-document-by-index-in-nodejs/42223774?noredirect=1#comment71611305_42223774)

Comment: does this type of syntax have a name (or is the convention documented somewhere?) - ie the array containing a template string -  i've never seen it before, it took me a while to figure out what i was looking at!  i still don't understand how/why the "array brackets" make the key name acceptable. (it did work for me though!)

Comment: update to earlier comment if it helps anyone else - it seems it is a "computed key", see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969495 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274327 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19837961

Answer (score 1):

As documented here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/,
you can increment an element in an array by dot notation.

The following example increase the first element of items by 1.

```
db.<collection>.update(
 <query>,
 { $inc: { "items.0": 1 } }
)
```

Comment: In my case the index of the array will be a variable. So, `"items.0"` won't work I guess. How to deal with this?

Comment: ```{$inc: {[`items.${idx}`]: 1}}```, where `idx` is your index.