# Template strings in mongoose update query with typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, template-strings

I want to use a template string in a mongoose update query using typescript.
The field I want to update is a Map called messages with string keys and array values of type Message.
So something like

```
interface Message {
   content: string,
   from: string,
   ...
}
userSchema = new Schema({
   ...
   messages: {type: Map, default: new Map<string, Message[]>}
}
```

The keys in the map are id's of the "message-partner", e.g. a userId or a groupId.
If a new message is sent from user with id *senderId* to user with id *receiverId*, I want to update both users' Maps.
For example for the receiver I'm calling something like

```
UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(receiverId, { $push: { `messages.${senderId}`: newMessage } })
```

However, this gives me the following errors:

[image]

Now if I change the template string to a usual string, for example:

```
"messages.1234"
```

the errors disappear.
Is there any workaround to this issue, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
One has to use a *ComputedPropertyName*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969495/16259630).

The corrected update-query looks like this:

```
{ $push: { [`messages.${senderId}`]: newMessage }
```